# PHP Starting an embed video

Tags: php, video

Ok I have a website, I'm setting up with blog videos.

I'm trying to get the video link to play in a separate window. I'm getting the right directory and name across, but for some reason it's not playing the video.

I have the webpage already detecting when a new video is in the videos directory and adding it to the list. So you go pick on **Todds_video_blog_10_16_2013.flv**. I need it to launch in a separate window.

It starts the `player.swf`

But I'm getting `error loading media.`

This is what I have so far.

```
<head>

<style type="text/css">

body {

    background-color: #000;

}

</style>

<?PHP 

$pvideo = urldecode($_GET['video']);
$filename = str_replace(' ', '%2F', $pvideo);
$vpath = pathinfo($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

?>

<embed src ="http://www.thetodd.tv/player/player.swf" width="560" height="420"    bgcolor="FFFFFF" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" flashvars="flvsource="<?PHP echo $vpath['dirname']; ?>/<?PHP echo $filename; ?>"&autoplay=false"></embed>
```

Comment: Did you look at the output? It looks like you're terminating your quotes prematurely here: flashvars="flvsource="<

Comment: Just a guess you have double quotes inside double quotes `flashvars="flvsource="`

Comment: That was the whole issue, I can't believe I missed it. Its good to have a second pair of eyes, Thanks!